# Using custom functions without including them

Tags: php, wordpress, function, include

I noticed that I can create a blank file in my Wordpress theme,
and use a function I've created in functions.php without including anything.

**How is this possible?**

My function in functions.php (

```
    function getContentFromID($int) {

        $my_id = $int;
        $my_id = get_post($my_id);
        $content = $my_id->post_content;
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
        echo $content;
}
```

ONLY content in test.php (and it gets the correct content if i replace `$scrapeID` with e.g. 135)

```
<?php getContentFromID($scrapeID); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress automatically include  function.php in the template. see http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 1):

By setting `auto_prepend_file`, it is possible to include a PHP file for every PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Something else has already included functions.php before test.php has been included. PHP puts everything in a single global scope unless you tell it otherwise somehow.

Comment: test.php isn't included I'm just linking to it.And "<?php getContentFromID($scrapeID); ?>" is the **only** content. Maybe you're right, but how does PHP know where to find the defined function?

Comment: You're linking *directly* to the physical test.php file on disk via the web server?

Comment: Uhm, no, sorry I misunderstood

I created a wp-page and used test.php as the template.

I'm then linking to example.com/getContent/?scrapeID=135

I understand now that you were right, but where does this happen? I want to use this feature on my projects.

Thx :)

Comment: I don't know WP well enough to explain *how*, only *why*.

Answer (score 0):

Because your new file is included by some other file, and this file which includes your file also includes the functions file, so the functions are visible to your file.